# Can I configure multiple tiles pointing to the same SP application with different default RelayState in Okta?

Tags: saml, okta, idp

I have a service (SP) using Okta SAML SSO. I want to expose multiple landing pages of my service as separate tiles in Okta for IdP-initiated login. Can I create multiple tiles pointing to the same SP application, but with different default RelayStates? Is this a reasonable approach? Will it work with other IDPs?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Okta but if you're intending to have multiple "links" to login to your app, I don't see why this wouldn't work. In a SP-initiated login, the SP provides the RelayState in the authn request. You'll have 1 trust between the SP and IdP, with different landing pages within your instance based on your "links"

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't be possible, b/c for each of the applications created in Okta you will have a separate set of IdP metadata, which you won't be able to configure on SP side.

UPDATE: Actually after posting the answer, I double checked, that it MAYBE possible if you create all those applications through API:

- they need to have the same `IdpIssuer`
- after creating all of them you need to clone a certificate from one application to all [Okta App API reference](https://%20https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/apps/#clone-application-key-credential)

I have not tried this approach by myself, but you may give it a try